# Wordpress application of openshift does not send email

Tags: php, wordpress, email, openshift

I installed wordpress as an Openshift application (web-liquibil.rhcloud.com). The user registration procedure is that an email with an password is sent to registrant. However, these emails, at best, arrived their destinations sporadically. Sometimes not at all. I search the forum, and found some notes in 2013/2014 that such emails frequently experienced problems. I am wondering if there is anything I should check, or something should be done on the Openshift side?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at the following link. There are often problems with the default php mail function. Try using SendGrid, mailgun, or your own gmail/yahoo/outlook email.

https://blog.openshift.com/using-sendgrid-for-email-services-in-a-wordpress-site/